# Calling functions prefix vs. infix in Haskell

Tags: haskell, factorization

I've been wanting to learn Haskell, so recently I started working through the ProjectEuler problems. While writing the following factoring code I noticed that calling `(/ n)` returns a `Float` while `` (n `div`) `` returns an `Int`. I thought that infix notation was simply syntactic sugar in Haskell? Could someone explain what is going on? I would also appreciate any comments / suggestions / improvements, thank you.

```
    import Data.List (sort)

    factor :: Int -> [Int]
    factor 0 = [1..]
    factor n =
        let f1 = [f | f <- [1..limit], n `mod` f == 0]
                where limit = ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
            f2 = map (n `div`) f1   --vs. map (/ n) f1
        in sort $ f1 ++ f2
```

Comment: Aside from `/` and `div` having different types, in `(/ n)` 'n' is the denominator, whereas in `(n \`div\`)` 'n' is the numerator.

Answer (score 16):

`div` and `/` are two different functions:

- `/` is defined in class [Fractional](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3a-47-) and it's meaning is an inverse operation to multiplication.
- `div` is defined in class [Integral](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3adiv) and it's meaning is division of integers with truncation toward negative infinity.

You're right, infix notation is just a syntactic sugar. The expression `x / y` is the same as `(/) x y`, as well as `div x y` is the same as `` x `div` y ``.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special going on.  The `div` function is part of the `Integral` class and is being more specifically inferred as `Int`, given your explicit type signature.  The `/` operator is part of the `Fractional` class.  These are two different functions, one is not syntactic sugar for another!